# Create a "like" for a user with Instagram API

Tags: php, javascript, api, curl, instagram

So, I'm working with the Instagram API, but I cannot figure out how to create a like (on a photo) for the logged in user. 
So my demo app is currently displaying the feed of a user, and it's requesting the permission to like and comment on behalf of that user. I'm using PHP and Curl to make this happen, creds to some guide I found on the internet:

```
<?php 
  if($_GET['code']) {
  $code = $_GET['code'];
  $url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
  $access_token_parameters = array(
    'client_id'                =>     '*MY_CLIENT_ID*',
    'client_secret'            =>     '*MY_CLIENT_SECRET*',
    'grant_type'               =>     'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'             =>     '*MY_REDIRECT_URI*',
    'code'                     =>     $code
        );

    $curl = curl_init($url);    // we init curl by passing the url
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);   // to send a POST request
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);   // indicate the data to send
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   // to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
    $result = curl_exec($curl);   // to perform the curl session
    curl_close($curl);   // to close the curl session

    $arr = json_decode($result,true);

    $pictureURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token='.$arr['access_token'];

    // to get the user's photos
    $curl = curl_init($pictureURL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $pictures = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $pics = json_decode($pictures,true);

    // display the url of the last image in standard resolution

    for($i = 0; $i < 17; $i++) {
    $id = $pics['data'][$i]['id'];

    $lowres_pic = $pics['data'][$i]['images']['low_resolution']['url'];

    $username = $pics['data'][$i]['user']['username'];
    $profile_pic = $pics['data'][$i]['user']['profile_picture'];

    $created_time = $pics['data'][$i]['created_time'];
    $created_time = date('d. M - h:i', $created_time);

    $insta_header = '<div class="insta_header"><div class="insta_header_pic"><img src="'.$profile_pic.'" height="30px" width="30px"/></div><div class="insta_header_name">'.$username.'</div><div class="insta_header_date">'.$created_time.'</div></div>';
    $insta_main = '<div class="insta_main"><img src="'.$lowres_pic.'" /></div>';
    $insta_footer = '<div class="insta_footer"><div class="insta_footer_like"><button onClick="insta_like(\''.$id.'\')"> Like </button></div><div class="insta_footer_comment"><form onSubmit="return insta_comment(\''.$id.'\')"><input type="text" id="'.$id.'" value="Comment" /></form></div></div>';

    echo '<div class="insta_content">'. $insta_header . $insta_main . $insta_footer .'</div>';
    }

  }
 ?>
```

Now, it might be a stupid question, but how do I make a like on a particular photo on behalf of the user? I'm used to using JavaScript to these kinds of things, therefore I've setup the Like-button with a JS function (which does not exist). But since the Instagram thing have been using Curl and PHP, I'm guessing I have to do the same thing here? I have no experience with Curl, and I do not understand how it works. It would be great if someone could give me a headsup on that as well. But first off, the liking. If it's possible to do it with JS, I'd be very glad. If not, please show me how to do it with PHP and Curl.

Here's a link to the Instagram developers site, which contain the URL you should send a POST request to http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/.

And if you're not to busy, I'd be really glad if you could show me how to make a comment on behalf of a user as well :)

Thanks in advance.

- Aleksander.

Comment: You should use the Instagram PHP API Class (instagram.class.php) which you can download from a quick search of GitHub.